# The Game Audio Tutorial Website

Tags: gameaudio, books, websites

I was planning on spending my weekend with The Game Audio Tutorial book, but I'm experiencing issues right off the bat.  In order to start, I'm supposed to download the tutorial level from the book's website, http://www.thegameaudiotutorial.com, but the site seems to be down!  I've tried Chrome, Internet Explorer, and my Android Browser, but I can never seem to load the page.

Assuming that many people here have looked into, or completed the book, do you know when the site went down, or if I'm doing something wrong?  I was really looking forward to reading this, so any help would be much appreciated!  Thank you!

UPDATE:  As of 6:15pm PST the site's back up!  Thanks for the shared concerns guys!

Comment: I already have most of all the files but the site isn't loading up for me either, I not sure whats going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I downloaded stuff from it a few days ago so it must've just gone down. Hopefully this'll be fixed soon!